# Conditional sampling based on column value

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have a dataset of 600.000 scientific papers from 2012 and 600.000 from 2014. I use couples of articles (2014-2012) as my unit of analysis, for citation analysis and the like.

I have a list of all articles that have a citation link (from 2014, to 2012), and what I want is, for each time a 2014-doc cites a 2012-doc (Cit=1), a control with another 2012-doc which is not cited by that 2014-doc, but which comes from the same journal as the original.

Toy example:

```
Citing <- data.frame(T2012=c("DOI1", "DOI2", "DOI3"), 
                     S2014=c("DOIa", "DOIb", "DOIc"), 
                     journal2012=c("Nature", "Science", "JoE"), 
                     cit=c(1,1,1))


Docs2012 <- data.frame(T2012=c("DOI1", "DOI2", "DOI3", "DOI4", "DOI5", "DOI6", 
                               "DOI7", "DOI8", "DOI9", "DOI10", "DOI11", "DOI12", 
                               "DOI13"), 
                      Journal=c("Nature", "Science", "JoE", "Nature", "Nature", 
                                "JoE", "Science", "JoE", "Nature", "Science", 
                                "Science", "JoE", "Science"))
```

... Now I want to add 3 rows for each Cit=1, where S2014 and journal2012 stay the same, Cit=0 and T2012 is a random DOI from the same journal as the Cit=1-case above. I have tried complicated loops to draw the T2012s, but they would take days given the size of my dataset. This is what I want to end up with:

```
Citing_withcontrol <- data.frame(T2012=c("DOI1", "DOI5", "DOI4", "DOI9", "DOI2",
                                         "DOI13", "DOI7", "DOI11", "DOI3", "DOI8", 
                                         "DOI6", "DOI12"),
                                 S2014=c("DOIa", "DOIa", "DOIa", "DOIa", 
                                         "DOIb", "DOIb", "DOIb", "DOIb", 
                                         "DOIc", "DOIc", "DOIc", "DOIc"), 
                                 journal2012=c("Nature", "Nature", "Nature", 
                                               "Nature", "Science", "Science", 
                                               "Science", "Science", "JoE", "JoE", 
                                               "JoE", "JoE"),
                                 cit=c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0))
```

Help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

One idea using `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)
merge(Docs2012 ,Citing, by.x = c('T2012', 'Journal'), by.y = c('T2012', 'journal2012'), all = TRUE)%>% 
   arrange(Journal, S2014) %>% 
   group_by(Journal) %>% 
   mutate(S2014 = zoo::na.locf(S2014), cit = replace(cit, is.na(cit), 0)) %>% 
   sample_n(4) %>%
   arrange(S2014, Journal, desc(cit)) %>%
   ungroup()

# A tibble: 12 × 4
#    T2012  S2014 Journal   cit
#   <fctr> <fctr>  <fctr> <dbl>
#1    DOI1   DOIa  Nature     1
#2    DOI4   DOIa  Nature     0
#3    DOI5   DOIa  Nature     0
#4    DOI9   DOIa  Nature     0
#5    DOI2   DOIb Science     1
#6   DOI10   DOIb Science     0
#7    DOI7   DOIb Science     0
#8   DOI11   DOIb Science     0
#9    DOI3   DOIc     JoE     1
#10  DOI12   DOIc     JoE     0
#11   DOI6   DOIc     JoE     0
#12   DOI8   DOIc     JoE     0
```

**Explanation**

- We first `merge` the two data frames on columns `T2012` & `Journal/journal2012`
- We sort the resulting data frame on `Journal` & `S2014` and `group_by` Journal.
- We carry the latest non-NA values forward (using `zoo::na.locf`) for `S2014` variable, and replace all `NA` with `0` in `cit` variable.
- We use `sample_n` to take our samples ( 4 in your case)
- We `arrange` and `ungroup` to get the desired output